# No module webots_ros2_driver

Tags: ros2, webots

We would like to implement our controller developed by our team on CF2 simulator.

We got the following error:

`$ ros2 launch ~/webots_ros2/webots_ros2_mavic/launch/robot_launch.py`

```bash
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ntukenmez3/.ros/log/2023-09-05-19-35-21-978685-ae-icps-407120-168970
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): Caught exception when trying to load file of format [py]: No module named ‘webots_ros2_driver’
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you used `ros2 launch [your-package] [your-launch-file]` correctly.
From the `ros2 launch --help`:

```
Run a launch file

positional arguments:
  package_name          Name of the ROS package which contains the launch
                        file
  launch_file_name      Name of the launch file
  launch_arguments      Arguments to the launch file; '<name>:=<value>' (for
                        duplicates, last one wins)
```

Could you add the logs mentioned at the start of the terminal error?

Do you have [Webots packages](https://index.ros.org/r/webots_ros2/github-cyberbotics-webots_ros2/) installed & sourced in your ROS 2 workspace?

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments, firstly we started to learn ros2 and Webots connection. But, we have not connected both of them yet. The following example did not work on the computer. We installed Webots and the related parts. You have an idea?  https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Advanced/Simulators/Webots/Setting-Up-Simulation-Webots-Basic.html  We're getting same error, we couldn't understand it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you're doing to setup your environment and the other things that you're running. The link to the tutorial is very helpful too. But if you're having trouble, understanding what you're exactly doing which might be slightly different from the tutorial could be important.

Comment: We tried the following example in ros2 webots tutorial, however it is still same problem. **ntukenmez3@ae-icps-407120:~/ros2_ws$** `ros2 launch my_package robot_launch.py`                                                                              `[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ntukenmez3/.ros/log/2023-09-07-10-29-05-643135-ae-icps-407120-1381651 [INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO [ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): Caught exception when trying to load file of format [py]: No module named 'webots_ros2_driver`

Comment: From this trace back I can think of only this step - start with installation of this package in the binary version with `sudo apt install ros-humble-webots-ros2-driver`. Did you do all of these [tasks from the part 1 of this tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Advanced/Simulators/Webots/Installation-Ubuntu.html#tasks)?

Comment: Thank you for your helpful recommendation, it works well now.

Comment: Cool, please accept the reply if it was helpful.